# extract one control of WP toolkit and edit it

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-toolkit

I want to extract only the DatePicker of the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) and I want to include an additional field to the DatePicker.

But how can I get only the code of the DatePicker and make me changes and than make a dll of it so I can use this control in my own apps?

Answer (score 0):

It's an open source project so get the source code from Codeplex and compile only the code of the control you need into a dll...

Comment: That is right. But the code contains many controls, so it is hard to figure out which files are necessary for the DatePicker.